# C# DataGridView.Rows.Add Issue

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I have a problem with DataGridView on C#

I have a class definition like this

```
class cls{
   bool is_checked;
   string id;
   string name;
   string description;

   constructor,getters,setters...etc
}
```

Here is my Form1.Designer.cs

```
this.datagridview = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
this.datagridview_checkbox_column = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();


this.datagridview .ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.datagridview .Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
this.datagridview_checkbox_column});
this.datagridview .Name = "datagridview";
this.datagridview .AllowUserToAddRows = false;
this.datagridview .Size = new System.Drawing.Size(565, 315);
this.datagridview .ColumnCount = 4;
this.datagridview .Columns[1].Name = "ID";
this.datagridview .Columns[2].Name = "Name";
this.datagridview .Columns[3].Name = "Description";


this.datagridview_checkbox_column.HeaderText = "";
this.datagridview_checkbox_column.Name = "datagridview_checkbox_column";

private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView datagridview;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn datagridview_checkbox_column;
```

And my Form1.cs

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initalize();
    }

    private void initalize() {
        Cls cls1=new cls(true,"string1","string2","string3");
        datagridview.Rows.Add(cls1.getIsChecked(), cls1.getId(), cls1.getName(), cls1.getDescription());
    }
```

My problem line is:

```
datagridview.Rows.Add(cls1.getIsChecked(), cls1.getId(), cls1.getName(), cls1.getDescription());
```

I get this error:

> The best overloaded method match for DataGridViewRowCollection.Add(params object[]) has some invalid arguments

But when I type like this:

```
datagridview.Rows.Add(true,"sss","sss","sss");
```

I dont get any compile error.Why ? Can you help me pls

Thanks for any advice...

Comment: Somene of your getXXXX methods doesn't return the appropriate type expected by the corresponding column

Comment: Comment that line and compile see whether it compiles? I hope problem is somewhere else

Comment: When you make the properties get/set are you still getting the error?

Comment: Sorry its my mistake.Actually visual studio's fault.When I rebuilded the project it is fixed itself.Thanks for replies gentlements